# How to arrange dates from old to new in vb scripting

Tags: vb.net, date, scripting

I'm developing a macro using extra attachmate. we have a 3rd party tool called CSS from where macro fetches required data. Now I'm trying to arrange dates from old to new.

Firstly I have changed date(10/01/14) to number(140110) and then extracted all values into array. From array is there any Function to sort the numbers or should i compare each value manually in loop?

After comparing the records from array, I have to write this data in different columns of single row.

IF my approach is incorrect then please suggest me correct way.

Thanks,
Yaswanth

Answer (score 0):

Your question talks about a lot of different things. I assume that you want to sort an array of integer. To do that you can use the [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

```
    Dim arr(2) As Integer

    arr(0) = 140110
    arr(1) = 130110
    arr(2) = 150110

    Array.Sort(arr)
```